# Adding an index column before the query in Google Sheet formula

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, sequence, google-query-language

I have a query which obtains data from another spreadsheet using IMPORTRANGE function.
However, I want to add an index before the result of the query, and it must be together with the query formula.

This query below works but I just need that extra column to show an index count from 1 to the nth  row of the query result.

```
=QUERY(
    IMPORTRANGE({ssid},"MASTERFILE!A:AC"),
    "select Col 2, Col4, Col7, Col8, Col9, Col11 where Col12 = 'ACTIVATED'",
    0
)
```

**Item no. should start with 1 and ends with the nth row provided by the query result.**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
={SEQUENCE(ROWS(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE({ssid},"MASTERFILE!A:AC"),
 "select Col2 where Col12 = 'ACTIVATED'", 0))), 
 QUERY(IMPORTRANGE({ssid},"MASTERFILE!A:AC"),
 "select Col2,Col4,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col11 where Col12 = 'ACTIVATED'", 0)}
```